# Returning a 'raw' scalar container from AT-POS method (rather than a Proxy instance) in a class that 'does' Positional?

Tags: raku

I'm attempting to implement a class that 'does' `Positional` that also allows me to update its values by assigning to the result returned by the `AT-POS` method. Eventually, I was able to concoct the following class that works as intended:

```
class Test does Positional
{
    has $.slot_1 is rw = 12;
    has $.slot_2 is rw = 24;

    method AT-POS(\position)
    {
        my $t = self;

        return-rw Proxy.new:

            FETCH => method ()
            {
                position % 2 ?? $t.slot_1 !! $t.slot_2
            },

            STORE => method ($v)
            {
                if position % 2
                {
                    $t.slot_1 = $v
                }
                else
                {
                    $t.slot_2 = $v
                }
            }
    }
}

my $test = Test.new;

die unless $test[2] == 24;

die unless $test[5] == 12;


$test[7] = 120;

die unless $test[2] == 24;

die unless $test[5] == 120;


$test[10] = 240;

die unless $test[2] == 240;

die unless $test[5] == 120;
```

Would it be possible to somehow (and: simply) return the *container* bound to `$!slot_1` (or `$!slot_2`) inside the `Test` class implementation?

Before I discovered the use of `Proxy` instances I attempted to `return` (and `return-rw`) the result of expression `position % 2 ?? $!slot_1.VAR !! $!slot_2.VAR`, because I'm under the impression that the `VAR` method gives me access to the underlying container, in the hope that I can simply `return` it. That didn't really work, and I do not understand why yet: I suspect it somehow gets coerced back to a value somehow?

So in other words: is it possible to simplify my `AT-POS` implementation in this particular situation?

Thanks,

Regards,

Raymond.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you do *not* want accessors for "slot_1" and "slot_2", and if I understand the question correctly, this would be my implementation.  I wouldn't call it a `Test` class, as that would interfere with the `Test` class that is used for testing.

```
class Foo {
    has @elements = 24, 12;

    method AT-POS(Int:D $pos) is raw {
        @elements[$pos % 2]
    }
}

my $f = Foo.new;
say $f[2];  # 24
say $f[5];  # 12

$f[2] = 666;
say $f[4];  # 666
```

Note that the defaults in the array have changed order, that's to keep the arithmetic in `AT-POS` simple.

Also note the [`is raw`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/is%20raw) in the definition of the `AT-POS` method: it will ensure that no de-containerization will take place when returning a value.  This allows you to just assign to whatever `$f[2]` returns.

Hope this made sense!

Also: the [Array::Agnostic](https://modules.raku.org/dist/Array::Agnostic) module may be of interest for you, to use directly, or to use as a source of inspiration.

Comment: Yes, this made a lot of sense: the `raw` trait was especially the thing what I was looking for. My not-so-aptly named class was really contrived and conjured up from scratch when I was trying to implement such functionality elsewhere. The `Array::Agnostic` implementation is indeed interesting and worth further study. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First off if you aren't going to use an attribute outside of the object, there isn't a reason to declare them as public, and especially not `rw`.

```raku
class Foo {
    has $!odd = 12;
    has $!even = 24;

    …
}
```

You can also directly return a Scalar container from a method. You should declare the method as `rw` or `raw`. (`raw` doesn't guarantee that it is writable.)

```raku
class Foo {
    has $!odd = 12;
    has $!even = 24;

    method AT-POS(\position) is rw {
        position % 2 ?? $!odd !! $!even
    }
}

# we actually get the Scalar container given to us
say Foo.new[10].VAR.name; # $!even
```

Note that even if you declare the attributes as public they still have a private name. The private attribute is always `rw` even if it isn't publicly declared as `rw`.

```raku
class Foo {
    has $.odd = 12;
    has $.even = 24;

    method AT-POS(\position) is rw {
        position % 2 ?? $!odd !! $!even
    }
}
```

---

If you are going to use a Proxy, I would consider moving the common code outside of it.

```raku
class Foo {
    has $.odd = 12;
    has $.even = 24;

    method AT-POS(\position) is rw {
        # no need to write this twice
        my $alias := (position % 2 ?? $!odd !! $!even);

        Proxy.new:
            FETCH => method () { $alias },
            STORE => method ($new-value) { $alias = $new-value }
    }
}
```

Of course the `?? !!` code is a core feature of this module, so it would make sense to put it into a single method so that you don't end up with duplicate code all over your class. In this case I made it a private method.

```raku
class Foo {
    has $.odd = 12;
    has $.even = 24;

    # has to be either `raw` or `rw`
    # it is debatable of which is better here
    method !attr(\position) is raw {
        position % 2 ?? $!odd !! $!even
    }

    method AT-POS(\position) is rw {
        my $alias := self!attr(position);

        Proxy.new:
            FETCH => -> $ { $alias },
            STORE => -> $, $new-value { $alias = $new-value }
    }
}
```

Again, not much reason to use a Proxy.

```raku
class Foo {
    has $.odd = 12;
    has $.even = 24;

    method !attr(\position) is raw {
        position % 2 ?? $!odd !! $!even
    }

    method AT-POS(\position) is rw {
        self!attr(position);
    }
}
```

---

Instead of `?? !!` you could use an indexing operation.

```raku
method !attr(\position) is raw {
    ($!even,$!odd)[position % 2]
}
```

Which would allow for a ternary data structure.

```raku
method !attr(\position) is raw {
    ($!mod0,$!mod1,$!mod2)[position % 3]
}
```

---

There was no need to write the `if` statement that you did as Raku usually passes Scalar containers around instead of the value.

```raku
(position % 2 ?? $t.slot_1 !! $t.slot_2) = $v;
```

Comment: @Brad_Gilbert everything looks great but I had trouble with the last example ('indexing operation'). Any help appreciated (see gist 'class Foo6') , thx! https://gist.github.com/jubilatious1/2adaaa1c6875edbd5624568e8979a62a

Comment: @jubilatious1 `!attr` is a private method, it can only be called by a method in the same class. It is also not a special method at all. The special method that gets called by Raku is `AT-POS`. That is that `!attr` method doesn't work unless you also copy the `AT-POS` one.

Comment: @Brad_Gilbert thank you. Updated the gist per your instructions and now classes Foo1 through Foo6 all work. Thanks again!

Comment: @jubilatious1 If the only thing that uses `!attr` is `AT-POS` then you can just put the code in it. I was only pointing out that functionality seems to be the only reason the class exists, so it may be used by more accessor methods in that class without duplicating code.

Comment: @Brad_Gilbert do you mean class Foo6? I'll play with the code some more, meanwhile feel free to leave a comment (with or without code) on my public gist. Thank you!